# Facebook Graph API and ActionScript

Tags: php, actionscript-3, facebook

*I'm setting out to develop a number of Facebook applications/games, which make use of some Facebook user information and stores game info in a database backend etc, in ActionScript 3.0.*

1. How can one leverage the [new Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api)
2. Should I use JavaScript or PHP as a "middle layer" or should I go with the [ActionScript Client Library](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/)?
3. Are there other libraries (Facebook / database / multiplayer related.) that could simplify the development of these Facebook games?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite vague, but the Graph API has a very scattered documentation. Your best bet would be to ask on the forums for help using it.

The new Graph API (compared to Facebook Connect) will give you more information and is (IMO) easier to use.

Javascript is virtually required, though setting up the actually code can be a pain. I prefer to handle few UI events (namely login / out) with Javascript and then pass it back to a PHP class that will handle any view changes or for storing in a database.

Which to go with would depend heavily on what you're developing. If you're developing Flash games then you should probably just go with the ActionScript library. Otherwise I would go with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe's ActionScript 3 SDK for the Facebook Platform seems to have gotten a major overhaul recently: http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/

Answer (score 1):

I have developed many Facebook Apps using adobe's actionscript 3 SDK. The documentation isnt great and is outdated.

I would be tempted to go the Facebook PHP SDK way. Purely to make updating easier. As I have found that Facebook is forever changing things and breaking things and not fully documenting their api. So changing some PHP is quicker then recompiling the swf and uploading.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Also the Graph API is ok but if you want to do more with Facebook look into FQL queries. It lets you do multiple queries in one with one object returned. Should be faster. Where as the Graph API you have to do separate requests.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Graph API & OAuth 2.0 & Flash
http://blog.yoz.sk/2010/05/facebook-graph-api-and-oauth-2-and-flash/

Answer (score 0):

The official library does indeed seem to be out of date. http://code.google.com/p/fbas/ seems to be up to date but less official.

What we did in our facebook app is just wrapped URLLoader requests around FB API calls, but we had problems with internet explorer 8.